# Meteor - Mongo won't update, object in array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am having some trouble with MongoDB in Meteor. Basically, I want to update a property of an object nested in an array. The whole object has the following structure:

```
product {
 _id: 
 some other properties
 template: {
    some other properties
    additionalFields: [
      { _id: 
        content: **update this**
      }
    ]
 }
}
```

I have written the following Meteor method:

```
 'products.update.field.content': function(product, field, update) {
    return Products.update(
        {_id: product._id, 'template.additionalFields._id': field._id},
        {$set: {'template.additionalFields.$.content': update }});
}
```

and to the call the method I use

```
onInputChange(event) {
    const { product, field } = this.props;
    Meteor.call('products.update.field.content', product, field, event.target.value);
}
```

If I put a callback `(error, update) => console.log(error, update)` in my method call I receive (undefined, 1). Yet when I console.log the product object content hasn't changed.

Can somebody help? 
Thanks

Comment: Should work, Perhaps the object did not have enough time to update or the query that mapped it to your props is not reactive.

Comment: Yes, @MasterAM the suggestion with the nonreactive props did it. Found the error, was something related. Thanks so much, took me a long time to find this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```js
Products.update({
  _id: product_id,
  'template.additionalFields': {
    $elemMatch: {
      _id: field._id
    }
  }
}, {
  $set: {
    'template.additionalFields.$.content': update
  }
});
```

Or you can go to the link for more details
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/